# bootstrap/jQuery fade opacity transition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, transition, fade

I am hoping someone can help!

I am trying to add bootstrap support to an existing jQuery/CSS site. Aside from realizing bootstrap changes a bunch of formatting that I have to fix - it seems to be affecting a popup transition I have, and can't seem to figure out. I hope you can help, thanks!

With regular jQuery/CSS (not UI), I am creating a modal dialog box that I popup.

BEFORE bootstrap - it would "fade" in the popup box (i.e., the opacity/alpha). However, AFTER adding the bootstrap .css/.js - now it just 
makes the background grey and totally opaque.

How do I fix it?

This is the code that works with just css/jQuery

```
<div class=sample-dialog>
  <div class=modal-overlay>
    <div class=modal-content>
      <div class=modal-body>
         random content
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

then the jQuery popup code that I call

```
function showModal() {

var m = $('.sample-dialog');
var o = m.find('.modal-overlay');
var c = m.find('.modal-content');
var b = c.find('.modal-body');

m.css('display','block');

o.animate({'opacity':.8},350);
b.animate({'opacity':1,'margin-top':0},350,function() {
  c.css('overflow-y','auto');
});
}
```

This "works" with just the jQuery/css.

HOWEVER, as soon as I add the bootstrap .js/.css file in my header, the *exact* same transition now shows *no* opacity (just a grayed out background).

Any idea on how to fix?

As a second thing - I also notice with the bootstrap files added, the transition seems to be 'choppy' as opposed to the nice 'smooth' one I had. If you have insight for that too, that would be great!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Well....first of all, unless you're not showing all the code.  Not sure what the variable o.animate would do. Nothing?  there is no o defined.  But other than that, possibly renaming the classes of your custom modal, to something that is not claimed by bootstrap.  So rename modal-body, modal-content to something else.  Otherwise its gonna use whatever settings bootstrap has

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to keep it 'succint' here and edit out any unnecessary code - and accidentally removed that. I've updated it now. The o is just an outer div class.

Comment: And okay... doing some 'quick' testing - interesting - had no idea bootstrap was using the 'modal-overlay' class, etc (just renaming those 'kind' of fixes some stuff - but I have a lot more css than just that code snipped). 

So question:

Is there anyway of being able to use my existing code without have to rename 100's of variable names (in css, my .js code, etc) in case bootstrap "may" be referencing a variable name? I do have the bootstrap .css included first (and mine 2nd, so I thought it would override the bootstrap .css)

Comment: 2nd question - is there anywhere (like an online search/lookup database) where I can check and see if bootstrap has 'claimed' a variable name?

Comment: just look in the bootstrap.css file.  Using ctrl-f in your editor, should be easy to find whatever names you need to replace.    But yeah, you need to replace all the names, in order to have your css mix with bootstraps.  No way around that.  Im pretty sure its not gonna be 100's of variables.  probably 10-20 at most.  But don't edit bootstraps variables.  Edit your own

Comment: hmm. 'bleah' - I thought it was going to be easy integrating bootstrap... meh. interesting though lol - never occurred to me to just use notepad doing the ctrl+f... (yeah, I can see bootstrap has the modal-body & modal-content which was definitely interfering...)...

Okay - I'll leave this question open for a day or so in case anyone else does have an easier solution (than doublechecking all my variable names) - if not, I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: pps - how do I accept this as an answer? can't seem to find a way to do that...

Comment: There is no answer.  I only commented.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the rules of bootstrap transitions are creating conflict, I remember working with version [4.0.0-alpha.6](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) it was impossible to modify the transition of the height in a model.

These would be the default values ​​of the modal transition (
with the `.fade` class)

_transitions.scss

```
.fade.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: initial;
}
```

This I think could help you;

Enables predefined transitions on various components

```
$enable-transitions: true (default) or false
```

[Documentation bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 /Customizing variables](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/)

Sorry if the bootstrap version does not help, but it's the only version I've worked with.